# AutoCenter slide in jssor slideshow

Tags: slideshow, center, jssor

Is there anyway to AutoCenter the image in jssor slideshow for both horizontal and vertical?

Thanks,
Jassim

http://www.xoompage.com

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your demo.

Anyway, please set $FillMode to 4(ActualSize).